# Jvm error -6 while starting Intellij-IDEA in 64 bit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, 64-bit

I have a problem starting Intellij IDEA (15.0.3) in 64 bit mode. When clicking on the idea6.exe I get this error (Failed to create a JVM error code -6):

[image: JVM error code 6]

This is my configuration:

- System:

  ```
    Windows 7 - 64 bit - 16GB RAM
  ```
- System Variables:

  ```
    IDEA_JDK_64: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74
    JVM_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 
    (1.7 version is needed for my dev activity)
  ```
- vm options: idea64.exe.vmoptions left as default

As a trial: I've tried various combinations like system variables pointing to the same JDK path or also to increase -Xmx value in idea64.exe.vmoptions, but the error is still there.

What can the root cause be?

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you defined both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME system variables? Also, if this doesn't solve your problem, try new intellij 2016.1.

Comment: Setting JRE_HOME didn't help: the same error still occured. Only upgrading to new version solved the issue. Thanks a lot for the tip ;)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - and it just started this morning for some reason. Currently using IntelliJ version 2016.1.1; I tried removing the JDK and installing the latest version - no luck. Copied the JRE to the IntelliJ directory - still didn't work (the startup message shows the correct path, so it is definitely attempting to use the correct JRE).  The 32-bit version works fine, it's just the 64-bit version that refuses to start.

Answer (score 36):

I solved problem in my case by deleting file **C:\Users\username\.IdeaIC2016.2\idea.exe.vmoptions**, because I created it before to customize VM options. File can have name **idea64.exe.vmoptions** if you overrode options under 64-bit version of Intellij IDEA.

Comment: for me actually deleting below worked:
C:\Users\username\.PhpStorm2016.2\.PhpStorm.exe.vmoptions

Comment: For Android studio: `c:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio2.3\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

Comment: For PyCharm: C:\Users\username\.PyCharmCE2018.1\config\pycharm64.exe.vmoptions

Answer (score 7):

Tracked it down to a mis-typed VM option in the end.

Somehow one of the lines in my idea64.exe.vmoptions file has been mis-typed. Instead of `-XX:UseParNewGC` I had `-XX:USeParNewGC`  (note the unwanted extra capital letter).

Correcting that fixed the problem - so check your .vmoptions file for typos if you get the -6 error on startup.

And note that there may be several copies of this file. The default is in the installation folder (eg "Program Files (x86)\Jetbrains\Intellij 2016.1\bin\idea64exe.vmoptions"),  but if you select "Help...Edit Custom VM Options" in the IDE it will create an override file in \Users\.IntellijIdea2016.1\idea64exe.vmoptions

Comment: The fact that "Edit Custom VM Options" creates an override file in users\.IntelijIdea was the key to solving my problem.  Shame that full uninstall including "settings" didn't remove this.

Comment: Thanks! You gave me the right direction. Seems that any typo in arg name causes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 on 64bit Windows 7 with JDK1.8.0_92.

Executing **`idea.bat` instead of `idea.exe`** worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think issue caused because you are using 32 bit launcher, and it has limitation as 4G for RAM.

So, if you will change value "-Xmx" to 2048  in c:\users\XXXXXX.WebStorm2016.3\webstorm.exe file -> this should help. Otherwise -> delete this file and wait when WebSrotm propose you to change it from IDE

Note: there are also webstorm.exe and webstorm64.exe files in your c:\Program Files

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, any option in `studio64.exe.vmoptions` led to this window.

Fixed by changing entry in `PATH`, it had old `JDK` folder, which pointed to different Java installation(Java 7) than `JAVA_HOME`(Java 8), after replacing it — Android Studio started normally with entries in `studio64.exe.vmoptions` file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, using Intelli J Idea Community Version 2017.3,  I found the idea.exe.vmoptions file in C:\Users\${UserName}.IdeaIC2017.3\config. I had increased the JVM Heap Memory to 4096MB from 512MB due to an earlier crash (-Xmx4096m). Changing to 1024MB seemed to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked once i deleted the vmoptions file created under the  C:USERS.IntelliJIdea2017.2\config folder.